# vb.net class assignment handling

Tags: vb.net

I have a node based hierarchy type thing where all the nodes are contained in a list but also each item in the list holds a reference to its parent in the hierarchy. For example

```
public class cItem
    public attributes as dictionary(of string, single)
    public parent as cItem
end Class 

....

public class database
    public stuff as new list(of cItem)
    public sub addItem(item as cItem)
        stuff.add(item)
        stuff.last().parent = functiontofindparentwithinstuff
    end sub
end class
```

question is whether the parent variable in cItem will hold a reference to the object in stuff list or will the item in stuff list just be duplicated into the items variable?

Comment: Is a LinkedList not an option for you? [MSDN Linked List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: hmm might be, i'm reading up on it now but it seems that i would have to contain the original data within the parent nodes rather than the list which is a bit of a problem. Is there a linked variable kind of thing?

Comment: A class is a reference type so it will just be a reference.

Comment: @HansPassant gave you the answer to the question you asked, but I don't quite understand what you're asking about the Linked List.

Comment: thats probably because i misunderstood why you recommended it to me, i thought you implied that a list of classes would own the data while linkedlist would reference it but that appears to be false. Why did you suggest linkedlist?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a sort of tree then all the add/remove of items should be done inside a function. This function would take care of setting the parent of the item property.

The parent variable should never be allowed to be modified by any other mean. This will let you keep the link between child and parent.

```
Class TreeItem

    Private _parent As TreeItem = Nothing
    Private _childs As New List(Of TreeItem)

    Public Sub AddChild(ByVal item As TreeItem)
        item._parent = Me
        _childs.Add(item)
    End Sub

    Public Sub RemoveChild(ByVal item As TreeItem)
        item._parent = Nothing
        _childs.Remove(item)
    End Sub

End Class
```